# Оформление исходного кода в дипломном проекте

Tags: c++, документация

Как оформляется исходный код в пояснительной записке, есть ли какие-то стандарты?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что правила оформления документов здесь не обсуждаются.

Comment: @Abyx, причём тут UML? С каких пор оформление документов не оффтопик на SO?

Comment: @Abyx, документация сделанная из UML это лишь следствие, не для этого он был создан, UML это общий язык моделей, поэтому это не оффтопик. Оформление кода это оффтопик на SO, т.к. к программированию отношения не имеют.

Comment: Всем спасибо,вопрос снят, можно закрывать тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно ответы на такие вопросы надо узнавать непосредственно у того, кто будет принимать работу. У всех преподавателей требования разные, разные и убеждения.

Нет какого-то четкого правила, кто-то использует табуляцию, кто-то пробелы, кто-то в 4 символа, а кто то в 2. Лично я использую пробел, 2 символа отступ. Т.е. табуляция везде в настройках разная, а пробел почти везде выглядит одинаково.